# How to leave only the column in gglot without blank spaces?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny

I created chart like this:

[image]

I would like to delete white blank spaces, and leave only the column.

[image]

My code:

```
 ggplot(melt(livechat_data())[c(8,9),],aes(x='',
                                            y=as.integer(value)
                                            ,fill=factor(variable, levels=c("nie","tak" )))) +
          geom_col(position='stack',width = .3) +
          coord_flip()+
          theme_minimal()+
          labs(x = "", y = "konwersja%",fill="Wysłano płatne zapytanie") +
          scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+
          theme( plot.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold"),
                 axis.text=element_text(size=15),
                 axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold"),
                 text=element_text(size=15),
                 legend.position = 'bottom')+
          scale_fill_manual(values = c("tak" = '#00cc00',
                                       "nie" = '#737373'))
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))` to your graph?

Comment: I tried, nothing has changed

Comment: I think I need to change height of plot - but no idea how to.

Comment: Try to set `width` argument to 2. E.g. `geom_col(position='stack',width = 2)`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem. What libraries are you using?

Comment: you can try `data.frame(y =1 , x= c(20,80)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y, fill = factor(x))) + 
   geom_tile()`

Answer (score 1):

Like some others have said, you can take your `scale_y_continuous` line and add `expand=c(0,0)` to remove the space around the y axis.  In your case, that won't work because your data is flipped: you need to use `scale_x_continuous`.  I show you an example below with dummy data to better and more clearly illustrate this point:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(0,0), y=c(20, 80), sam=c('This', 'That'))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_col(aes(fill=sam)) +coord_flip()
p
```

[image]

**Coord_flip() + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) removes TOP and BOTTOM spaces**

```
p + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

**Coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) removes LEFT and RIGHT spaces**

```
p + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

Put 'em together, and you get this:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

No more border or space.  So although you mentioned you tried `scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))` you should be able to tell from above that this won't work to remove the "upper" and "lower" spaces in your graph: it will only remove spaces on the left and right side.  Like the example I posted, your plot is flipped with `coord_flip()`, so you need `scale_x_continuous`.